# SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numerc liteal

Tags: javascript, adobe, acrobat

Hey my code in Adobe Acrobat gives me this Error.
Can someone maybe help ?

```
if (this.getField("Anwendungsbereich.Auswahl").valueAsString!="" && this.getField("Anwendungsbereich.Auswahl").value<4 || this.getField("Anwendungsbereich.Auswahl").valueAsString!="" && this.getField("Anwendungsbereich.Auswahl").value<1a ) {
```

Comment: What is `1a` here?

Answer (score 0):

Hey in the end of the line you have:

```
this.getField("Anwendungsbereich.Auswahl").value<1a
```

JS interprets *1a* as a variable name. But it is not possible to create a variable with leading numeric symbols (must start with a letter, underscore (_), or dollar sign ($)).